# How to correctly interpret relay schematics

Tags: pcb, relay, schematics, eaglecad

I am copying a schematic in EAGLE to make a battery protection board (https://www.homemade-circuits.com/battery-over-discharge-protection/)

I am very unexperienced in writing relays in schematics, and am unable to know exactly how to wire up the relay in the schematic editor, because the relay symbol is very different than what I am accustomed to. Not to mention, the names of the pins is the only thing I have to work with, since that's the only help they give. (The relay they show in there schematics has no schematic resemblance whatsoever):

[image]

**Below is a schematic of a typical relay, Displaying the pin names:**

[image: schematic 1]

(Courtesy of [circuit-diagramz.com](https://circuit-diagramz.com/use-relay-example-basic-schematic-circuit-diagram/))

**Below is another Schematic of the same type of relay from Autodesk EAGLE.** I wrote the same names for the pinouts in green, but I'm not 100% sure if I'm correct. For starters the switch is flipped upside down, and for another, instead of N/O and N/C. it just says 'S' and 'O':

[image: schematic 2]

Comment: It looks fine what you have done.

Comment: So I named everything right in the eagle schematic? @Andyaka

Comment: @XBuilder Yes...

Comment: i think that you need to disassemble a relay and examine how it operates ... doing that would clear up your misunderstanding